# Most appropriate file format for storing cross references

Tags: python, json, xml, reference, yaml

I need to store some meta information and dependencies between my assets, in files that I can use to do some validations down the line.

Taking JSON as an example, my metadata file would look like this (`/publish/path/metadata/poster.json`):

```
{
    'created_by': 'John',
    'creation_date': '12112018',
    'version': '005',
    'creator_comments': 'Updated to latest published images for Poppy',
    'path_to_file': '/publish/path/images/poster.png',
    'dependencies': [
                     '/publish/path/metadata/poppy.json',
                     '/publish/path/metadata/dwarf.json',
                     '/publish/path/metadata/giant.json'
                     ]
}
```

and (`/publish/path/metadata/poppy.json`):

```
  {
        'created_by': 'Daug',
        'creation_date': '12102018',
        'version': '003',
        'creator_comments': 'Poppy is more red on top',
        'path_to_file': '/publish/path/images/poppy.png',
        'dependencies': [
                         '/publish/path/metadata/poppy_drawing.json',
                         '/publish/path/metadata/poppy_effect.json'
                         ]
    }
```

I am looking for a file format would be most appropriate fit to do the following

1. be able to store references to other files
2. is supported by python libraries that can process the references
3. can be read easily by humans
4. viewer or browser support that allows me to traverse the referenced files

What do you think fits best to my use case?

Comment: What result do you want when loading the file? Should the content of the reference be loaded, so `dependencies` would end up as a list of dictionaries?

Comment: With YAML, you could invent your own `!include` tag. In PyYAML you can define what to do when loading a node with such a tag.

Comment: Tinita, I would need the references to be resolved to list of dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

JSON, YAML, and XML are all popular file formats with some pros and cons. There are other file formats as well such as [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml), [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) and others. Here is a overview of JSON, YAML and XML:

**JSON**

- Pros

  - very popular with good, native support in many language core libraries
  - supports schemas via JSON Schema (http://json-schema.org/) with filepath support
  - validation tools can validate filepaths and is discussed, e.g. https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/98
  - can reference external files as shown in Swagger spec JSON implementation
- Cons

  - hard to read multiple lines since line feeds are represented as `\n`
  - less ideal for creating by hand
- Implementations

  - Google app credentials
  - NPM `package.json`
  - Swagger / OpenAPI

**YAML**

- Pros

  - popular and easy to read multi-line values if you have them
  - specification is available: http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html
  - can reference external files as shown in Swagger spec YAML implementation
- Cons

  - does not appear in as many core language libraries as JSON
- Some Implementations

  - Ruby on Rails configuration file
  - Swagger / OpenAPI

**XML**

- Pros

  - very large files can be handled by SAX parsers, think GBs
  - standardized schema: https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/schema
- Cons

  - very verbose and more difficult to read
  - XML libraries are used to parse and create, e.g. libxml2.
- Some Implementations

  - RSS/Atom

**Summary**

- JSON if you have limited amount of data and either no data with multiple line values, or multi-line values that humans are not expected to read. This is good for configuration files because an external dependency is often not needed
- YAML if you have more data that needs to be human created/edited, including multi-line values
- XML if you have a lot of data, in the GB range

For your viewer requirement, you could use a schema to identify a file link and then modify an existing viewer to add a link when present. Of course, you can always create your own from scratch as well.

For your requirements as you've stated, it seems JSON and YAML would be the most appropriate and popular. A benefit is that there are many generic tools to convert JSON and YAML back and forth. Automatic conversion is not as prevalent for other file formats.

Answer (score 0):

YAML was designed to include human readable forms of data such as yours, (but there are multiple ways of representing data in YAML that are not so readable)

XML, I've seen described as having the readability of binary combined with the inefficiency of ASCII.

JSON has a bit too many double quotes to make its actual data stand out. And if you want to edit the data by hand, you really have to take care with trailing comma's in arrays and objects.

---

There is of course no viewer or browser that directly supports your format, but if you start with JSON it is possible to write a JavaScript program that displays each dataset properly with hyperlinks. You can do the same when you start with XML via de DOMparser that is built into the browser. There are also YAML parsers in javascript that can do the same for YAML based data, but these would have to be installed and loaded into the browser.

---

If you don't want to program in javascript, I would go for putting the data in YAML and have a Python program that (recursively) looks at all the individual YAML files and generates HTML from these, including correct hyperlinks (to the HTML "version" of the dependencies) and either links to the images, or in place display of the images. Make the program smart enough to only (re-)generate the HTML if the corresponding file containng the YAML document has a newer timestamp.

This is similar to how some blog systems work that generate static views from markup. And since you want to process the data using Python anyway, you should be able to re-use some of the code you write.

You should make your `/publish/path/metadata/poster.yaml`:

```
created_by: John
creation_date: 2018-11-12
version: 005
creator_comments: Updated to latest published images for Poppy
path_to_file: /publish/path/images/poster.png
dependencies:
- /publish/path/metadata/poppy.yaml
- /publish/path/metadata/dwarf.yaml
- /publish/path/metadata/giant.yaml
```

As you can see you don't have to write dates as strings, YAML directly supports the YYYY-MM-DD format (where it is unclear if your creation_date is the MMDDYYYY as used in the USA or the DDMMYYYY as is more wideley used in other English speaking countries). How you display dates in your HTML is of course your preference.

With your YAML you should adhere to the latest spec (1.2 from 2009) and use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). If you go for YAML 1.1 (in which case you can use PyYAML), you'll have to quote and define your versions as scalar strings as PyYAML otherwise interprets `version: 015` as the number 13. `ruamel.yaml` also correctly round-trips and writes such integers again with leading zeros. If your version would contain non-numerical data, then YAML automatically loads this as a string (no need to quote).

For dumping the HTML there are many options, using some library where you create a tree structure and then dumping that has the advantage that you cannot generate invalid HTML. But even if you generate HTML "by hand", you should have your output relatively quickly debugged.

The conversion program can of course also check that all references exist and warn you if they don't.

---

A simple program that does the above (with not so good looking HTML as output):

```
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarint import ScalarInt

yaml = YAML()

def convert_data(d, fp, level=0):
    """recursively write a loaded YAML document as HTML"""
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        print('<table>', file=fp)
        for k in d:
            print('<tr><td>', file=fp)
            convert_data(k, fp, level=level+1)
            print('</td><td>', file=fp)
            v = d[k]
            convert_data(v, fp, level=level+1)
            print('</td></tr>', file=fp)
        print('</table>', file=fp)
        return
    if isinstance(d, list):
        print('<ul>', file=fp)
        for elem in d:
            print('<li>', file=fp)
            convert_data(elem, fp, level=level+1)
            print('</li>', file=fp)
        print('</ul>', file=fp)
        return
    if isinstance(d, str) and d and d[0] == '/':
        if d.endswith('.yaml'):
            h = Path(d).with_suffix('.html')
            print('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(h, d), file=fp)
            return
        if d.endswith('.png'):
            print('<img src="{}">'.format(d), file=fp)
            return
    if isinstance(d, ScalarInt):
        if d._width is not None:
            # integer with leading zeros
            print('{:0{}d}'.format(d, d._width), file=fp)
        return
    if isinstance(d, date):
        # print the date in DDMMYYYY format
        print('{:%d%m%Y}'.format(d), file=fp)
        return
    print(d, file=fp)

def convert_file(yaml_file, html_file):
    data = yaml.load(yaml_file)
    with html_file.open('w') as fp:
        print('<html>\n<body>', file=fp)
        convert_data(data, fp)
        print('</body>\n</html>', file=fp)

def main():
    for yaml_file in Path('.').glob('*.yaml'):
        html_file = yaml_file.with_suffix('.html')
        if True or not html_file.exists() or \
           html_file.stat().st_mtime < yaml_file.stat().st_mtime:
            convert_file(yaml_file, html_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You could of course make the links and images explicit by using tags ( `!link /publish/path/metadata/poppy.yaml` and `!img /publish/path/images/poster.png` and have classes with a constructor for these tags that then dump appropriate HTML. This does however not necessarily give you better readable YAML.

Comment: I should add that in YAML 1.2 Core Schema, `003` will be loaded as an integer, soleading zeroes are stripped from integers and floats, so if you want to keep them, you should also use quotes in 1.2

Comment: @tinita As I indicated, and as can be seen from the output of the program I added to the answer, those leading zero's are not stripped in `ruamel.yaml` by default.